# find flux outward a sphere cutted with $y\le-4$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, surfaces

$$D=\{x^2+y^2+z^2\le 25,y\le -4\}. \qquad F=\{z^2,y^2,x^2\}$$

In order to find the total flux going outward D I need to evaluate two fluxes(or maybe not ? ):

- the first one is the flux of the circular region surface $x^2+z^2\le 9$ (which is the intersection between the sphere and $y\le -4$)
- and the second one is the surface created by cutting the sphere

I calculated the first flux by first parametrizing the surface and then by evaluating the double integral over if :

$$\iint\limits_{S_1} F\,ds$$

So I have $r(\theta)=(3\cos\theta,-4,3\sin\theta)$ with $0\le \theta \le 2\pi$

and the normal vector is $n=(0,-1,0)$. and eventually the flux will be = $-144\pi$

The problems start when I try to calculate the flux of the second surface :

So i have $r(\theta,\phi)=(p\sin\phi\sin\theta,p\cos\phi,p\sin\phi\cos\theta)$ with $0\le \theta \le 2\pi$,$\cos^{-1}{(-4/5)\le \phi \le \pi}$

The normal shoud be : $n = (-p^2\sin^2\phi\sin\theta,-p^2\sin\phi\cos\phi,-p^2\sin^2\phi\sin^2\theta)$

And when I multiply $F(r(\theta,\phi))n = -p^4\cos^2\theta(2\sin^4\phi\sin\theta+\sin\phi\cos\phi)$

Is that really What I should put in the integral? (in order to find tge flux of the second region)

What I'd like to get is the total flux! What would you do to?

Comment: What is $\vec F$?

Comment: yeah sorry I edited

Comment: note that $div \vec F=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [**divergence theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem) we have

$$\iint_S \vec F \cdot \vec n dS=\iiint_D \operatorname{div}\vec F dV=\iiint_D \operatorname 2y\, dV$$

and by cylindrical coordinates we have

- $z=r\cos \theta$
- $x=r\sin \theta$
- $y=y$

$$\iiint_D \operatorname 2y\, dV=\int_0^{2\pi}\,d\theta \int_{-5}^{-4} 2y\, dy\int_0^{\sqrt{25-y^2}}r\,dr$$

([solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%202yr%20dr%20dy%20dt,%20t%3D0..2pi,y%3D-5..-4,r%3D0..(25-y%5E2)%5E.5) $-\frac{81}2 \pi$)

Comment: what are the constrains of $D$ ? because I have problem parametrizing the entire surface

Comment: @NPLS The simplest way in that case is to observe that $div(F)=0$ then the flux over any closed surface is equal to zero by divergence theorem.

Comment: but the dif(F) isn't equal to 2y ?

Comment: @NPLS Opsss...yes sorry of course...I don't know what I read. Anyway it is convenient proceed by that way by divergence theorem.

Comment: yep, but I don't know how to parametrize that thing

Comment: @NPLS Ok I'll add the set up, maybe in that case it is better proceed by cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: @NPLS How you can see that's a very effective method and the volume integral are much simpler since we deal with scalar quantities. You are welcome! Bye

Comment: wait, in the second integral you did evaluate the integral between $4\le y\le 5$ isn't it $-4 \le y \le -5$ ?

Comment: @NPLS Yes sorry I calculate for $y\ge 4$. I fix that!